# aligning three squares with same class and position absolute one near another

Tags: html, css

I was asking myself if is posible to align some elements with same class and `position: absolute` one near another. After one hour of testing i find a solution for this: http://jsfiddle.net/hv01ad1r/1/

However, if I try to make them `display:inline-block` , elements will have some space between them.

http://jsfiddle.net/hv01ad1r/2/

I want to understand why this unexpected space is appearing and how can I get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use inline-block, the `div` is inside the line like normal text. So the mysterious space is a blank space between the divs in your code. Remove the spaces between the `divs` in your code:

```
<div id='container' style="height:100%;width:200px;position:absolute">
<div class="square">square 1</div><div style="height:100px;width:100px;display:inline-block"></div><div class="square">square 2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7wLrhdte/1/

Comment: You're right ~! But it still remains one space below. Can i fix that somehow?

Comment: Yes, this has to do with the line-height of the surrounding div, try:   `#container {  line-height: 0; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/7wLrhdte/3/